# how to access json object that is in a form of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new in javascript I need help in accessing an elements of an array from the data returned by an API. below is an example of the data I want to manipulate:

[{"merchant_id":"90151","merchant_name":"Wimpy"}]

the above json format is returned by an api, I tried to access merchant_name value but I was getting nothing due to lack of knowledge.

below is what I tried:

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/vcl/retrieve/"+url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {  
          console.log (response);
          const data = JSON.stringify(response);
          const info = JSON.parse(data);
          var merchant_name = info.merchant_name;
          console.log(merchant_name);
        })
```

I am getting undefined as the value instead of the merchant name

Comment: info[0].merchant_name

Comment: You have an array with an object. You are not referencing the object in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [0] first, cause i think its a list.

```
console.log(info[0].merchant_name);
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance it is wirking quite well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you stringify and parse, but you can do e.g. `info.pop().merchant_name`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains why you simply cannot use `info.merchant_name`.

The reason you are not able to access the merchant_name is because the response is returning an array with one object instead of simply returning an object.

Since it is returning an array, you need to access the first index of the array (it starts at zero) before you can read the object properties.

Example:

```
let merchant_name = info[0].merchant_name;
console.log(merchant_name);
```